# NG-TABLE - mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, ngtable

I'm trying to use ngTable with require.js and head.js but I'm getting the following error:

*Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:*

```
function (angular) {
return factory(angular);
}
```

Here is my require config:

```
(function(head){
        'use strict';
        head.js(
            { jquery: "../vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"},
            { require: "../vendor/requirejs/require.js" },
            { angularjs: "../vendor/angular/angular.js" },
            { uiRouter: "../vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js" },
            { angularTable: "../vendor/ng-table/ng-table.js"}
        ).ready("ALL", function(){
            require.config({
                appDir: '',
                baseUrl: '',
                paths: {
                },
                shim: {
                    angularjs: {
                        deps: ['jquery'],
                        exports: 'angular'
                    },
                    uiRouter: {
                        deps: ['angularjs'],
                        exports: ""
                    },
                    angularTable:{
                        deps: ['jquery', 'angularjs'],
                        exports: ""
                    }
                }
              });
              require(['config'], function(config){
                  // app bootstrap and start
              });
        });
    }(window.head));
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the problem a while ago but I didn't have the time to post it. The RequireJs documentation says that one has to load all scripts that call define via the RequireJs (ngTable does have a define call in it). As you can see above, I am loading ngTable using head.js. The solution it would be to remove that define call from ngTable. Hope it helps someone !

Comment: I don't like the solution of removing the UMD header since it breaks bower dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `head.js` but from a bit of searching it appears that you are using it to load jQuery, AngularJS, etc. Then, in RequireJS your code lists jQuery, AngularJS, etc. as dependencies. You generally cannot have it both ways: load a RequireJS module outside and inside RequireJS. The solution that appears most appropriate, without knowing your application, would be to load all of the modules with RequireJS.